# How to remove/disable the google map in contact us page?

Tags: google-maps

We are trying to remove/disable the google maps in our contact us page by using some additional CSS code, but it doesn't work

Just wondering if there are any other ways to get rid of the google map on the page?

.google_map_shortcode_holder {display: none;}

Comment: .google_map_shortcode_holder {
    display: none;
}

Comment: Just remove the Google Map code?

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 way you can remove the google map short code from contact us page or you can add below css.

```
#map-holder {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: This is actually the right answer, since setting even the parent div to "display: none;" should disable the map in the child div.

Comment: Please comment the reason if you decide to downvote an answer (directed at downvoter not the owner of the answer, cheers)

Comment: @Waren thanks for appreciation. and i agree whenever we do downvote comment is necessary help user to understand :).